# querySelectorAll working find in JSFiddle, but receive "The string did not match the expected pattern" as injected code

Tags: javascript, safari, browser-extension, selectors-api

I have a JSFiddle that matches any element that has the "background-color" style attribute. When I use it as an injected script inside a Safari Extension on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), I get the error "The string did not match the expected pattern", and I cannot continue the script beyond this point. Why would this happen?

```
var possibilities = ['[style*="background-color"],[style*="background-color"]'],
    searchFor = /\bbackground-color/,
    cssProp = 'background-color',
    styles = document.styleSheets,
    i, j, l, rules, rule, elem, res = [];

for (i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
    rules = styles[i].cssRules;
    l = rules.length;
    for (j=0; j<l; j++) {
        rule = rules[j];
        if (searchFor.test(rule.cssText)) {
            possibilities.push(rule.selectorText);
        }
    }
}
possibilities = possibilities.join(',');
possibilities = document.querySelectorAll(possibilities); // "The string did not match the expected pattern" ERROR
l = possibilities.length;
for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    elem = possibilities[i];
    res.push(elem);
}
alert(res.length + ' matches!');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqv4tkc3/)

Comment: What page are you trying to apply this to? Also, JSFiddle uses iframes and injection to show the results view. An extension would need to take special measures to interact with that.

Comment: I'm using it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: How are you injecting this script? If it's an extension you're writing, show that code.

Comment: Thank you both. I found out that rule.selectorText could sometimes be undefined, so I check for that before pushing it to the array.